# Gameobject not being set active in 'catch'. I've checked everything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Trying to check if there's internet connection or no. If there is no internet connection, I want to set active a panel showing 'no internet connection'.

I dragged the panel to the inspector. The script which sets this panel active is on a gameobject which is active in hierarchy.

Here is the code:

```
public GameObject NoInternetConnectionPanel;

private void Start()
{
    //Check Internet Connection
    InvokeRepeating("CheckInternetConnection", 0f, 1f);
}

private void CheckInternetConnection()
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
    request.Method = "HEAD";

    request.BeginGetResponse(result =>
    {
        try
       {
            using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Internet connection available");
                }
                /*else
                {
                    Debug.Log("No internet connection");
                }*/
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Debug.Log("No internet connection");
            NoInternetConnectionPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }, null);
    
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndCheck());
}
private IEnumerator WaitAndCheck()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);  
}
```

The debug log message "no internet connection" is being shown in console. But the 'NoInternetConnectionPanel.SetActive(true)' is not working.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's most probably because it is being executed on another any thread which is not supported by most of the Unity API. In general you shouldn't be using `WebRequest` at all but rather use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

Also not btw that your `WaitAndCheck` routine doesn't do anything at all.

I would rather use something like e.g.

```
public GameObject NoInternetConnectionPanel;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return CheckInternetConnection();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}

private IEnumerator CheckInternetConnection()
{
    using(var request = UnityWebRequest.Head("http://google.com"))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        var connection = request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success;

        NoInternetConnectionPanel.SetActive(! connection);

        if(connection)
        {
            Debug.Log("Internet connection available");      
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No internet connection");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Instead of using a we request at all you can also use a simple [`Ping`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ping.html) which is often used with e.g. `8.8.8.8`, Google's global DNS server.

```
private IEnumerator CheckInternetConnection()
{
    var ping = new Ping("8.8.8.8");
    var maxPingTime = 1f; // maximum time to wait before declaring the ping as failed
    var connection = false;
    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed <= maxPingTime; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        if(ping.isDone)
        {
            connection = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    NoInternetConnectionPanel.SetActive(! connection);

    if(connection)
    {
        Debug.Log("Internet connection available");      
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("No internet connection");
    }
}
```